# applying changes in phpmyadmin configuration

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, server

I am trying to change the configuration of phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.16.

I found /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php, and added

```
set $cfg['TablePrimaryKeyOrder'] to 'DESC';
```

at the end (before the `?>`)

However, I have seen no change in behaviour in phpMyAdmin, even after restarting Apache.

How do I apply this configuration?

Comment: Did you try to edit `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` instead?

Comment: There is no `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`. I tried creating the file by copying `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`, but that didn't help.